# URL rewrite problem on IIS7.5

Tags: url-rewriting, iis7, windows-server-2008

My aim is to create Friendly URLs for a website hosted on IIS 7.5.

The site has 3 pages with the following URLs:

- `http://www.example.com/contact.php?langid=1&title=contact`
- `http://www.example.com/technology.php?langid=1&title=technology`
- `http://www.example.com/clients.php?langid=1&title=clients`

I'd like the URLs in this format :

- `http://www.example.com/1/contact/`
- `http://www.example.com/1/technology/`
- `http://www.example.com/1/clients`

When I create the friendly URLs in the IIS wizard it uses the same URL pattern

```
^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

for each of the rules.
This just means all 3 URLs redirect to the same page.

the `web.config` file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
            <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^clients\.php$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^langid=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;title=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="clients.php?langid={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^contact\.php$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^langid=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;title=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="contact.php?langid={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
                </rule>
</rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*/)clients\.php\?langid=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;(?:amp;)?title=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}/{R:3}/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL2" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*/)contact\.php\?langid=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;(?:amp;)?title=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}/{R:3}/" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions how to do this correctly?

Comment: At a guess you should change the `RewriteUserFriendlyURL2` action url to something like:  `{R:2}.php?langid={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}` if title always equals the filename.

Comment: that's great, exactly what i was looking for.... if you want to put it as an answer i'll mark it as correct... thanks...

Comment: Cheers, was away from a computer when I commented so didn't want to answer without confirming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the action is hard coded to use the same filename. You could add some additional conditions and duplicate the rules, but a simpler option would be to change the `RewriteUserFriendlyURL2` action url to:

```
{R:2}.php?langid={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}
```

If the `title` parameter always equals the filename.